# Property of type Visibility in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In a WPF application, when you need to trigger the visibility of an element of the View from the ViewModel, there are basically two methods:

### Method 1 : using a `bool`

```
class ViewModel
{
    public bool IsMyImageVisible { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibility" />
</Window.Resources>

<Image Visibility="{Binding IsMyImageVisible, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibility}}" />
```

### Method 2 : using a `Visibility`

```
class ViewModel
{
    public Visibility MyImageVisibility { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<Image Visibility="{Binding MyImageVisibility}" />
```

### Questions

1. Is "method 2" still  MVVM compliant ?
2. When should I use "method 1" ?

**EDIT**: changed the questions to be less opinion based.

Comment: This question is too much _opinion based_ to be discussed here. I would try on Code Review site. Anyway **IMO**: 1) because it's strictly speaking more MVVM. 2) Yes it breaks it but I do not think it's a problem, I think we have to be little bit flexible, they're guide lines, not rules. 3) No.

Comment: @Adriano: why does it break the separation of concerns? Both methods really ends up doing the exact same thing. Do you consider that the first method also break the separation of concern?

Comment: about 1) because you bind the concept of **visibility** in the UI with the concept of "is visible to user" in the model and it may not be the same (for example image may be muted, displayed in a smaller list, accessible somewhere else or whatever). Your UI will change often, your model may won't change at all for years. That's why I think you may do it or not (I don't think you must **always** search abstractions), in simple cases it may be OK to expose some details.

Comment: Final point is that you expose an enum specific of WPF. If you're _planning_ to port your UI to, let's say, web then this will break it. If you do not think you'll ever port your application to another platform then you can live happy with it (anyway frankly speaking...probably you'll have to rewrite much more than few properties in your model).

Comment: I'm writing too many comments anyway...I would point another thing. Here we're discussing if it's better an enum or a boolean for that property. I think we should consider the true problem: **NAME** (then its **meaning**) of that **property**. If you name it "Visible" then you're putting an UI detail (visibility) to model. Model should have **attributes related to domain** (deleted? not accessible? hidden by user?). If you **describe model using domain words and concepts** then visibility won't even come to your mind.

Comment: I'm glad you post that last comment. That's what i was thinking when I asked "Do you consider that the first method also break the separation of concern?". I was really worried I could be taking the whole thing the wrong way by exposing `IsVisible` in the first place. Thank you very much for all your comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second option binds your ViewModel to a specific technology (WPF). Another technology like some web framework will have a different Visibility enumeration. You also might need to add the WPF reference to your model project which might not be a good idea for some scenarios (since all consumers of that project will now have to include that reference as well).

If you do not need cross-framework compatibility in your ViewModel, then you can use the second one without any other drawbacks.

Comment: It's true `Visibility` is linked to WPF. But it's very likely that your are already using WPF stuffs in your ViewModel, like `ICommand` or `Dispatcher`.

Comment: Wrong. ICommand or Dispatcher are classes of the Windows namespace, nothing to do with WPF.

Comment: Well, `Visibility` is defined in `PresentationCore.dll` and `Dispatcher` in `WindowsBase.dll`. I never saw any project referencing   only one of these two dlls.

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon it's not only a point of where they're defined. ICommand may be used everywhere (now it has been **moved to System.dll**) but of _domain_. ICommand is restricted to WPF domain but Visibility is.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following scenario:

The following interface design decision is made: Instead of hiding the image, it will be made %10 opaque, like a ghost. Now, if you took the second option, you would have to change your viewmodel code because of an interface design change. However, if you took the first option, then you modify the interface (perhaps add an BoolToOpacity Converter) to reflect that change. The first option is more in keeping with MVVM philosophy. And if you have seperate people working on interface design and viewmodel code, then they would not have to interfere in each other's work.

Comment: Is this flexibility really worth the sacrifices on the clarity of the XAML? Also, in my experience, changes in the View often requires a change in the ViewModel; so I think, it's an acceptable drawback.

Comment: Well, it's a matter of preference. I personally find the clarity of the XAML not reduced at all. (By the way, you might try placing the converter in a shared resource to clean up the XAML a bit). But if you are thinking that it is an acceptable drawback, maybe MVVM is not the pattern for you after all. Consider this: the presence of the BoolToVisibility converter in many MVVM out-of-the-box frameworks suggests that the first approach is more suited to MVVM.

Comment: Still, `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` is very limited: it will never return `Visibility.Hidden`. If you need that, you need to write your own converter, or add `Triggers`. All of this can be avoided with a  `Visibility` in the ViewModel.

Comment: +1 I think this is the the best point to avoid Visibility in model. Longer or shorter code (best practice are seldom shorter...) doesn't really matter more than _intentions_ (and if you don't care about that just don't use MVVM). @BenoitBlanchon imagine you're displaying a list of images, flag may simply be "Deleted" (boolean). First version you do not show deleted images, 2nd version you add a flag to show them (muted). In this case you'll need to change name, type and behavior of model too...

Answer (score 2):

I think it really comes down to what you're going to do with that property. Some views of your application might simply make the image visible/not visible but when creating another view maybe you want to display a whole new template based on the availability of the image.

In that case it would make the Visibility property a bit strange.

Comment: Well, in most cases, you just want to make the control visible or not... but you're right, the `bool` opens more possibilities.